# create jquery tabs based off a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-ui-tabs

**EDIT:** I am massively changing the question to reflect my new understanding of the problem. I have now a JSON file of variable length `{"CORE 1":"alfa", "CORE 2":"beta", ...}` on which I'd like to generate some (https://jqueryui.com/tabs/ jquery) tabs names based on the keys and use the values for the content of the tab.

```
<div id="tabs_3">
      <ul  class="clicked">
        <li><a href="#tabs_3-1">CORE 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs_3-2">CORE 2</a></li>    
      </ul>

      <div id="tabs_3-1">      
        # alpha
</div>

      <div id="tabs_3-2">
        # beta
      </div>
                </div>
```

how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript

```
var data = [{"CORE":"tabs-1","title":"alfa"},{ "CORE":"tabs-2","title":"beta"},{"CORE":"tabs-3","title":"gamma"}];

var stringData = "";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
  stringData += "<li><a href=#"+data[i]['CORE']+">"+data[i]['title']+"</a></li>"
}
console.log(stringData);
$(".list").append(stringData);

$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

and the html is look like this

```
 <ul class="list">  </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">...</div>
<div id="tabs-2">...</div>
<div id="tabs-3">...</div>
```

notice that the id attribute is equal to a CORE data inse of the json file

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to change the structure of your object to be able to add tabs dynamically inside jquery for example: this----> `{"CORE 1":"alfa", "CORE 2":"beta", ...}` transform to this ----> `[{"CORE":"alfa"},{ "CORE":"beta"}, ...]`
and you will access the data using a for or whatever bucle you want.

Comment: I see. could you expand a bit on the actual implementation? it must sound rather noobish butI am having trouble designing a function that does that.